# Topology Issue after sculpting

Tags: modeling, rigging, sculpting, topology

Apologies for the interruption, but I've come across an issue with the topology of my 3D model.
Prior to sculpting, the topology was perfectly fine, but after completing the sculpting process, it turned out to be quite dreadful.

Therefore, my question is:

*Is there a way to adjust the topology without altering the shape of the model?*

[image: Here is a screenshot of the Model]

Comment: If you slide some edges it may not change the shape, yes

Comment: Try the Slide Relax Brush in sculpt mode. It lets you slide the geometry while trying to respect the general shape of it. By default you can drag those edges manually, while holding Shift it automatically tries to make the quads and even size

Comment: Thank you, mate. It worked like a charm.